# Change in state based on sorted variable in R

Tags: r, database, variables, dplyr, var

I have a variable called "exposed" and I know already the sum of exposed people over time, "index" is how many people the individual meet in a week: have a look to understand

| i | exposed | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | y | 22 |
| 2 | y | 12 |
| 3 | y | 6 |
| 4 | n | 54 |
| 5 | n | 3 |

So I have 3 exposed individuals and 2 are not.

```
t <- 5
#I know that each i in t :

sum(exposed[i]) <- c(3,4,1,4,5)
```

I created this line of code to capture the change in data:

```
evol <- list()

for(i in 1:t){evol[[i]]<- df}

for (i in 2:t) {
  # condition

}
```

If the number of exposed at [t] is higher than the number of exposed at [t-1] so individuals with exposed==n and have a higher index change the exposed variable from n to y.

If the number of exposed at [t] is lower than the number of exposed in [t-1] so individuals with exposed==y and have the lower index change the exposed variable from y to n.

My question is: what is the condition that I have to write to have in:

A data set that looks like this:

```
evol[[1]]
```

| i | exposed | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | y | 22 |
| 2 | y | 12 |
| 3 | y | 6 |
| 4 | n | 54 |
| 5 | n | 3 |

should change to the data hat looks like this:

```
evol[[2]]
```

| i | exposed | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | y | 22 |
| 2 | y | 12 |
| 3 | y | 6 |
| 4 | y | 54 |
| 5 | n | 3 |

If the data looks like this:

```
evol[[3]]
```

| i | exposed | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n | 22 |
| 2 | n | 12 |
| 3 | n | 6 |
| 4 | y | 54 |
| 5 | n | 3 |

I hope I made it clear;

Any ideas please;

kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to change the vector `exposed`.

```
change_exposed <- function(exposed, index) {
  stopifnot(length(exposed) == length(index))
  for(i in seq_len(length(index))[-1L]) {
    if(index[i] > index[i - 1L]) {
      exposed[i] <- if(exposed[i] == "y") "n" else "y"
    }
  }
  exposed
}
change_exposed(evol[[1]]$exposed, evol[[1]]$index)
#[1] "y" "y" "y" "y" "n"
```

Assign the result to `exposed` to actually change the data set.

```
evol[[1]]$exposed <- change_exposed(evol[[1]]$exposed, evol[[1]]$index)
identical(evol[[1]], evol[[2]])
# [1] TRUE
```

---

### Data

```
evol <- list()
x <- 'i     exposed     index
1   y   22
2   y   12
3   y   6
4   n   54
5   n   3'
evol[[1]] <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
x <- 'i     exposed     index
1   y   22
2   y   12
3   y   6
4   y   54
5   n   3'
evol[[2]] <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but I didn't understand where can I add the (sum(exposed[i]) <- c(3,4,1,4,5)) to have the aimed answer. kind regards

Comment: @Angelo_231 You cannot assign a value to a sum, I don't understand what you mean by that line of code. Where do those numbers come from if they are not in the data? Do you want `exposed[i] <- sum(c(3,4,1,4,5))`?